# Relational algebra : Parenthesis issue

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I have been given this homework on relational algebra.

[image: RA problem]

I am having trouble figuring what differs between both relation instances as the parenthesis are placed otherwise in the second case. I would say that both return the same result but I don't think it is the case.

If anyone could provide an explanation that would be nice ! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the second variant is an error.  The outer projection looks for `sname` but is only passed `sid`.